# Is it grammatically correct to say: Don't look at life ordinarily but as extraordinarily?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Should it be: don't look at life ordinarily but as extraordinary?

Comment: That sentence makes (almost) perfect sense the way it is written. Can you clarify exactly what you want to know, for example, should it be that, as opposed to what?

Comment: I think you want:  *Don't look at life as [being] ordinary, but as extraordinary.*  But if you are going to use the *-ily* form you don't want the *as* before *extraordinarily*.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing a word, the word ***as***. You appear to be making an *as/as* statement. As such, you need both of them, and your comparisons should be between two of the same part of speech (that is, compare adjectives to adjectives or adverbs to adverbs. Otherwise it's a bit like comparing apples to oranges.)

> Don't look at life **as** ordinary but **as** extraordinary.

*Ordinarily, by the way, is an adverb (it modifies the verb "look" in your sentence, and means "[in general](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ordinarily)

> Ordinarily, it is my husband who mows the grass.

[Ordinary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+ordinary&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), however, is an adjective, which modifies *life*.

Also, [but](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/conjunctions.htm) is a conjunction which sometimes takes a comma before it.

> Dont look at life as ordinary, but as extraordinary.

Comment: "Don't look at life ordinarily, but extraordinarily" is also grammatical but means something different.